# Why do I have to terminate my statement before String.Length update

Tags: c#, string

When using the string.Length attribute in a statement that was previously split, it seems to return a *[ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* unless the statement was terminated.

Consider this:

```
// Throw exception?
var X = "[Hello World. This is a test]";
X = X.Split('[')[1].Split(']')[0].Remove(0, X.Length - 1);
```

Versus having to terminate the statement with a semi colon which doesn't throw any exceptions.

```
// Works perfectly fine
var X = "[Hello World. This is a test]";
X = X.Split('[')[1].Split(']')[0];
X = X.Remove(0, X.Length - 1);
```

How come that I have to terminate the statement for the Length to return the proper length of the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assignment to `X` doesn't happen until the very last step, because you're not assigning anything to `X` before that. As a result of that, `X.Length` looks at the original value of `X`, not the intermediate value.

Comment: But then how come X = X.Remove(0, 1).Remove(X.Length - 1, 1); works?

Comment: My excuses - It also seem to throw an exception.

Comment: @dotTutorials That should compile, but throw an exception at runtime. Is that what you're getting now?